# Magnolia upgrade from 5.3.4 to latest

Tags: magnolia

I'm trying to upgrade my Magnolia CE to the latest version from the 5.3.4.

On the documentation it's recommended to not directly jump to the 5.7 but to go to the latest minor release of the current version before going to the 5.7.

> Update to your latest minor release version first before upgrade to recent major release. A May 2017 example: a customer was considering an upgrade from 5.4.1 to 5.5.4 (latest release at that time). The correct sequence would have been: 5.4.1 → 5.4.12 → 5.5.4 instead of  5.4.1 → 5.5 → 5.5.4 .

So, I've checked and the latest minor release of the 5.3 is the 5.3.19.
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Release+notes+for+Magnolia+CORE+5.3.19#ReleasenotesforMagnoliaCORE5.3.19-Howtoupdatefromearlierversions

But all the download links on the nexus are broken.
The latest available download for the version 5.3 is the 5.3.13.

I'm a bit confused. Did any of you have already migrated from the 5.3.x to any major release?
Did the 5.3.13 will do the job?

Thanks for your help,
Regards,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Maintenance releases for previous major versions of Magnolia are available to Magnolia On-Premises customers only (i.e. customers that have an active subscription to Magnolia On-Premises).' https://www.magnolia-cms.com/support/maintenance-policy.html, Unfortunate enough that's the policy.

In this case I see two alternatives:

- Sending an email to info@magnolia-cms.com
- Since you want to upgrade
  to later release anyway, just giving it a shot in test env. or
  similar.

Cheers,

Comment: I've try your link, but I got an "Access Denied" error page. It asked me to login but I don't have any account on the Nexus.

Comment: And the latest 5.3 minor version on SourceForge is the 5.3.12.

Comment: Last update to CE was 5.3.12. Last update to EE was 5.3.19

Comment: @Dekx Apparently that's the best practice to do but it doesn't mean upgrade would fail If you skip a version or even a major version, so If I were you, I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with the 5.3.12 version.